# change grideview icon with another icon when clicked

Tags: gridview, menu, icons

I created a gridview menu and I wanna to change each icon when I click on it with another icon.
i have 4 icon to click that each one open new activity, I want when icon clicked in gridview first clicked icon change to another icon then open activity.

actually make a graphical menu.

this is ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.public_news, R.drawable.azmoon_news,
            R.drawable.azmoon_result, R.drawable.super_user,
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

and this is MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity

                Intent i;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PublicNewsActivity.class);
                        // passing array index
                        i.putExtra("id", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AzmoonNewsActivity.class);
                        // passing array index
                        i.putExtra("id", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AzmoonResult.class);
                        // passing array index
                        i.putExtra("id", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuperUser.class);
                        // passing array index
                        i.putExtra("id", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

thank you.